# In tabulator how to use selected data for bottom row calcs

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a fairly simple table, and am currently using a bottom calculator formatter:

```
export let myTable = new Tabulator("#my-table", {
  columns:[
      {title:"ID", field:"id", headerSort:false, visible:false, responsive:2},
      {formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", align:"center", bottomCalc:"sum", hozAlign:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
        cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
      }},
      {title:"Name", field:"address", width:300, bottomCalc:"count"},
      {title:"My Data", field:"mydata", bottomCalc:avNoOutsiders},
      ],
});
```

```
export let avNoOutsiders = function(values, data, calcParams){
  // filter outliers
  let myArray = filterOutliers(values);
  // filter any null or falsy values
  let av = average(myArray);
  return av
}
```

The code isn't super important, but what I'd like to be able to do is allow the user to de-select a row to exclude the value from this calculation.

The problem is, I don't understand how to access the `isSelected()` function here, I think it's just the `row()` I can access it. I can access the `values` (all the column values) but there's no selection data there, I can access the `data` - the whole table, but there's no way of determining which row it is, or whether it is selected or not.

My current direction of thinking is either

1. **using `bottomCalcParams`**. I don't understand how I would do this. This function returns a `getRow() is not a function` error:

```
function cellIsSelected(cell){
  selected = cell.getRow().isSelected()
  return {isSelected:selected};
}
```

or

2. **Writing individual functions for each bottom calc.** This doesn't work as I can't call the table inside the table calcs - `var selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows()` causes a circular error if I try to put that into a column calc function. I can reference the table inside the table.

Any ideas how I can access the row selection data to make a column calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but one way to achive that would be to create a hidden placeholder column which can be updated to true/false upon row selection/deselection. Then you can use the values of this hidden column in your `bottomCalc` function to exclude rows that are not selected.  Here is an example where selecting a row will re-trigger bottom calculation and average the age of all selections:

```js
const dataSet1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '21', gender: 'male' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '5', gender: 'female' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Christine Lobowski', age: '42', gender: 'female' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Brendon Philips', age: '80', gender: 'male' },
]

const calcAvg = (values, data, calcParams) => {
  let selected = data.filter((row) => row.isSelected)

  values = selected.map((i) => i.age)

  let avg = values.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0) / values.length

  return avg ? avg : ''
}

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: dataSet1,
  columns: [
    {
      formatter: 'rowSelection',
      titleFormatter: 'rowSelection',
      cellClick: (e, cell) => {
        cell.getRow().toggleSelect()
      }
    },
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', bottomCalc: calcAvg },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: '', field: 'isSelected', visible: false }  // Selection placeholder column
  ]
})

const selection = (row) => {
  row.update({ isSelected: row.isSelected() })
  table.recalc()
}

table.on('rowSelected', selection)
table.on('rowDeselected', selection)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Cheers Tim, this looks like it'll do the job! Funnily, I was looking for the "selected" column in the Column Calc data, tried a couple of approaches to make it appear but it didn't. I'll give it a whirl and mark solved if this does the job (99% sure it will!).

Comment: Yep it worked, I had to upgrade to 5.2.2 for some of the functionality to work. Posted a slightly amended version of the answer to cover different columns with the same function.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim's answer got me 95% of the way there.

Note that some of his responses don't work on Tabulator v4.9:

```
const selection = (row) => {
  row.update({ isSelected: row.isSelected() })
  table.recalc()
}

table.on('rowSelected', selection)
table.on('rowDeselected', selection)
```

I thought that figuring out a way round this might take longer than updating, so I plunge and updated to 5.2.2, which was less painful than expected. I had multiple columns to calculate, so rather than running a different function for each one, I passed the field name into the function via the `bottomCalcParams`, thus:

```
const calcAvg = (values, data, calcParams) => {
  let selected = data.filter((row) => row.isSelected)
  // Add your calcParams here:
  values = selected.map((i) => i[calcParams.field]) 

  let avg = values.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0) / values.length

  return avg ? avg : ''
}

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: dataSet1,
  columns: [
    {
      formatter: 'rowSelection',
      titleFormatter: 'rowSelection',
      cellClick: (e, cell) => {
        cell.getRow().toggleSelect()
      }
    },
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', bottomCalc: calcAvg, bottomCalcParams:{field:"age"} },
    { title: 'Remaining Teeth', field: 'teeth', bottomCalc: calcAvg, bottomCalcParams:{field:"teeth"} },
    { title: 'Personality Quirks', field: 'quirks', bottomCalc: calcAvg, bottomCalcParams:{field:"quirks"} },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: '', field: 'isSelected', visible: false }  // Selection placeholder column
  ]
})
```